# How do I filter specific months out of my dataset? Alternatively, how do I only show years in x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a dataset with wage rates of two genders for 10 years. The columns are Males, Females and Date -> where all 12 months of each year are on the rows.

I'm making a line graph and i just want to filter out month 1, 6 and 12 from each year and only make a line graph out of that.

Or a better preference would be to show years (and not months) on the x -axis but have all the month points in the line graph still.

Please help me code.

I have this code so far;

```
wage_data <- read.csv("Final.csv")

wages_males <- wage_data$Males
wages_females <- wage_data$Females
wage_data$Date <- as.Date(wage_data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
wages_dates <- wage_data$Dates
wage_data$Dates <- factor(wage_data$Dates, levels = unique(wage_data$Dates))

# maximum and minimum values for Females
max_female <- wage_data[which.max(wage_data$Females), ]
min_female <- wage_data[which.min(wage_data$Females), ]

# maximum and minimum values for Males
max_male <- wage_data[which.max(wage_data$Males), ]
min_male <- wage_data[which.min(wage_data$Males), ]


ggplot(wage_data, aes(x = Dates)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Females), size = 2, alpha = 0.3, color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Females), size = 0.5, , group = 1, color = "red") +
  geom_label_repel(data = rbind(max_female, min_female), aes(y = Females, label = Females), 
                   size = 4, color = "red", nudge_y = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Males), size = 2, alpha = 0.3, color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Males), size = 0.5, group = 1, color = "blue") +
  geom_label_repel(data = rbind(max_male, min_male), aes(y = Males, label = Males), 
                   size = 4, color = "blue", nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(title = "Average Hourly Wage Rate Between 2013-2023 of Males(Blue Line) & Females(Red     Line)",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Average Hourly Wage Rate in 2024 CAD",
       color = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 7))`
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: You should share a sample of your data to allow others to help you. You can use `dput(head(wage_data))` and copy&paste the result along with your question. Others can then run this code to get your data. I would also recommend to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting your `Dates` to a factor stick with proper dates. Then you could use `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y")` to show only the years on the x axis.

Additionally, you could simplify your code by reshaping your data to tidy format so that gender becomes a variable of your data. Finally, I did some styling using the `ggtext` package to color the genders in the title.

Using some fake random example data to mimic your real data.

```r
# Make fake example data
Dates <- seq.Date(
  as.Date("2013-01-01"),
  as.Date("2023-01-01"),
  by = "month"
)
Dates <- format(Dates, "%m/%d/%Y")

set.seed(1)

wage_data <- data.frame(
  Dates = Dates,
  Males = runif(length(Dates), 20, 40),
  Females = runif(length(Dates), 10, 30)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggtext)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

wage_data <- wage_data |>
  dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(Dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Dates, date), names_to = "gender")

wage_min_max <- list(
  wage_data |> dplyr::slice_max(value, n = 1, by = gender),
  wage_data |> dplyr::slice_min(value, n = 1, by = gender)
) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()

ggplot(wage_data, aes(x = date, y = value, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = wage_min_max, aes(label = round(value, 2)),
    size = 4, nudge_y = 1, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(
    title = paste0(
      "Average Hourly Wage Rate Between 2013-2023 of ",
      "<b style='color: blue'>Males</b>",
      " & ",
      "<b style='color: red'>Females</b>"
    ),
    x = "Date",
    y = "Average Hourly Wage Rate in 2024 CAD"
  ) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    # axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 7)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

When I run the whole ggplot function you've provided, it showing me "Error in seq.int(r1$year, to$year, by) : 'from' must be a finite number". Any suggestions why that's happening to me?